# Is there a way to make a chain of variables, each one being dependent on the one that came before?

Tags: python, variables, random

Im  triyng to make a program that takes into account the number of one variable (chosen at random) to decide the value of the next, and i need to repeat this 11 times (so n3 would depend of n2, n4 of n3, etc.) the idea would be a code like:

```
def rayuela_cuerpo():
    n2 = random.choice([0,1])
    if n2 == 0:
        n3 = random.choice([1,3])
        return n3
    elif n2 == 1:
        n3 = random.choice([0,2])
        return n3

    if n3 == 0 or n3 == 1:
        n4 = random.choice([1,3])
        return n4
    elif n3 == 2 or n3 == 3:
        n4 = random.choice([0,2])
        return n4 

    if n3 == 0 or n3 == 1:
        n4 = random.choice([1,3])
        return n4
    elif n3 == 2 or n3 == 3:
        n4 = random.choice([0,2])
        return n4
```

but that it would work.

Comment: could you say what you mean by "it would work"?  e.g. why are you returning values, does this mean you care about intermediate values and what about just returning a list of 11 values?  could you make a slightly more realistic example, your existing code is just an inefficient version of `rayuela_cuerpo = lambda: random.randrange(4)`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Two questions: 1) Do you actually need to remember all the n2, n3, etc. values, or do you just need to  figure out the *last* value in the sequence? 2) I see that the condition used to check `n2` is different from the condition used to check `n3`. **What actually is the rule**? (Is there some pattern to it? Why is the condition different for these two? Will it be different again for the others?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A way that you could do what you are saying is to do:

```
def random_simulation(entry_number): # generate a random number based on the input number given to the function
    if entry_number == 0:
        return random.choice([1,3]) # returns the value to where this function was called
    elif entry_number == 1:
        return random.choice([0,2]) # returns the value to where this function was called

def rayuela_cuerpo():
    origin_number = 0
    for _ in range(11): # run through the function 11 times and update the value for the next time the function is run
        origin_number = random_simulation(origin_number)
    return origin_number # return the last number to be generated from the for loop
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to use it later so this is how the final code ended up looking like:

```
def random_simulation(entry_number): # Genera un número aleatorio basado en un input dado a la función.
if entry_number == 0 or entry_number == 1:
    return random.choice([1,3]) # Devuelve el valor hacia dónde es llamada la función.
elif entry_number == 2 or entry_number == 3:
    return random.choice([0,2]) # Devuelve el valor hacia dónde es llamada la función.

def rayuela_cuerpo():
    origin_number = 0 
    posiciones_casillas = []
    for _ in range(12): # Recorre la función 12 veces y actualiza el valor para la próxima vez que es corrida la función.
        posiciones_casillas += [origin_number]
        origin_number = random_simulation(origin_number)
    return posiciones_casillas # Devuelve las 12 casillas aleatorias generadas guardadas en una lista.
```

Thanks Andrew Ryan for the HUGE help

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).